# Dependecy injection error while working with a multi-module Quarkus project. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I'm trying to separate an existing project by modules but I'm getting the following error:

> [1] It's not possible to automatically add a synthetic no-args constructor to an unproxyable bean class. You need to manually add a non-private no-args constructor to com.gestorsistemas.chupacabra.base.invoicemirror.invoice.usecase.impl.NFCeSyncServiceImpl in order to fulfill the requirements for normal scoped/intercepted/decorated beans.

Before, when it was a single-module, everything worked perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

This is the root **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project ...">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.gestor</groupId>
  <artifactId>chupa-cabra</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
      <module>base</module>
      <module>dominio</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-scheduler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
      <artifactId>dotenv-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>23.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

This is the base module, where's the **bean class** that I'm getting the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.gestor</groupId>
        <artifactId>chupa-cabra</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>base</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

This is the **bean class** within this module:

```
JBossLog
@ApplicationScoped
public class NFCeSyncServiceImpl extends AbstractInvoiceSyncUseCase<NFCe> implements NFCeSyncService {

    @Inject
    public NFCeSyncServiceImpl(NFCeRepository repository,
                        @Channel(NFCE_RESPONSE) MutinyEmitter<InvoiceResponse> emitter){
        super(repository, emitter, log);
    }

    [...]
}
```

The repository dependecy is within the same module and satisfies the requirements.

Here is the **pom.xml** file that belongs to the module that has the base module as the dependecy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.gestor</groupId>
        <artifactId>chupa-cabra</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>dominio</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-anywhere</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/src/main/resources/sajdbc4.jar</systemPath>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gestor</groupId>
            <artifactId>base</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is where I inject the **bean class**:

```
JBossLog
@Transactional
@ApplicationScoped
class NFCeSolicitationServiceImpl implements NFCeSolicitationService {

    private final NFCeUseCase nfCeUseCase;
    private final NFCeRepository nfCeRepository;
    private final NFCeSyncService syncService;
    private final InvoiceCommonUseCase invoiceCommon;

    NFCeSolicitationServiceImpl(NFCeUseCase nfCeUseCase,
                                NFCeRepository nfCeRepository,
                                NFCeSyncService syncService,
                                InvoiceCommonUseCase invoiceCommon) {
        this.nfCeUseCase = nfCeUseCase;
        this.nfCeRepository = nfCeRepository;
        this.syncService = syncService;
        this.invoiceCommon = invoiceCommon;
    }
    [...]
}
```

I've tried using the *jandex-maven-plugin*, putting the **beans.xml** file inside the module, but nothing seems to work. I'm almost sure that this isn't a code level problem, because it worked before I detach the modules, I guess it is some configuration on the maven project structure that I'm missing out, but not quite sure.

Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The error was that the **pom.xml** files from the modules were missing the Quarkus plugins, so I added the following to all **pom.xml**, and everything worked fine:

```
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                    <goal>generate-code</goal>
                    <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>compile</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>testCompile</id>
                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <source>17</source>
            <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```